# How to delete a node fetched by Relay from all connections that include it?

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, graphql

Relay provides the [`NODE_DELETE` mutation config](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-mutations.html#node-delete) to "remove the node from a connection and delete the associated record from the store".

But what happens when for instance node A is included as a connection from nodes B1, B2, B3... (an unknown number of them), and our application has Relay containers showing those B nodes and their respective connections to A? If we delete A just from the B1 connection via `NODE_DELETE`, will all Relay containers get updated, or just the one showing B1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since every node has a globally unique ID, Relay knows that the nodes with IDs specified in `deletedIDFieldName` were deleted, and can exclude them from all connections in which they existed.

Comment: So why do we need to specify the parentID ? It looks odd. Can't we just specify the `deletedIDFieldName` ?

Comment: From what I can tell, `parentID` seems to be optional. In fact, it's not used for node deletion at all. Instead, it's [passed to edge deletion](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/src/mutation/RelayMutationQuery.js#L450) to remove it from the connection. Anyway, when the result comes back, Relay takes the `deletedIDFieldName`(s) and [deletes the node(s) and all connections it's (they're) part of](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/src/traversal/writeRelayUpdatePayload.js#L158).